# Train a model to draw bounding boxes on certain objects in an image?

Tags: computer-vision, google-cloud-vision, vision

Is it possible to use GCP Machine Learning products to train a model to draw bounding boxes on certain objects in an image? I'd like to be able to feed labeled images and have it predict where that label would belong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this, where the Tensorflow machine learning library is used:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-object-detection-application-tensorflow

A note:

When you say that you want to be able to feed labeled images and have it predict where that label would belong, i assume you mean where that object is present in the image in terms of the bounding box coordinates. If so then the library should take care of that for you, your job is just to train the network with your labeled images.